# Trying to initialize super class property in swift but run into errors

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and I am currently learning about initializers. I am running into an issue with overriding the parent class initializer. 
I get a compiler error "Use of 'self' in property access 'ImageTexture' before super init initializes self"

I would like a new image to get used when special badge class is called

here is the special badge class where I get the error

```
class SpecialBadge: Badge {

    enum BadgeAnimation: Int {
        case GrowAndShrink = 0, Rotate, Shake
    }

    override init(requestType: UDRequestType) {

        let animation = BadgeAnimation(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(3)))
        self.imageTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BadgeTeal")
        super.init(requestType: requestType)


        switch animation! {
        case .GrowAndShrink:
            growShrink()

        case .Rotate:
            rotate()

        case .Shake:
            shake()
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error when I call on line:

```
self.imageTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BadgeTeal")
```

before calling `super.init(requestType: requestType)`

My parent class;

```
class Badge: SKSpriteNode {

    var requestType: UDRequestType
    var imageTexture: SKTexture?

    init(requestType: UDRequestType) {
        self.requestType = requestType

        if let texture = imageTexture {
            super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(48, 48))
        } else {
            let newTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BadgeMagenta")
            super.init(texture: newTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(48, 48))
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to initialize imageTexture so it can use a different image before calling the initializer in SpecialBadge, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That `if let` binding will always fail because `imageTexture` has no default value. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of the order in which you do things. This is illegal:

```
self.imageTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BadgeTeal")
super.init(requestType: requestType)
```

This is legal:

```
super.init(requestType: requestType)
self.imageTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BadgeTeal")
```

The rule is that you must complete initialization of the superclass before doing anything special to your own class.

Comment: Hey, I tried that approach but my goal was to use SKTexture(imageNamed: "BadgeTeal") but imageTexture is null when the initializer gets called and it uses SKTexture(imageNamed: "BadgeMagenta") from the Badge class. Is there a way to override the super.init that is being used inside the Badge class initializer?

Comment: I'm not seeing what the problem is. Just call `super.init` dead first, and do everything else afterwards.